# several lists - list comprehension to calculate an equation

Tags: python, list, zip, list-comprehension, complextype

I have 5 **complex** lists; `a,b,c,d,e.`

I'm trying to compute `'m'` where:

```
m = abs([a*(b+e) - c* d] / [e*(c+a)] )
```

This is my code:

```
m = []
mm = []
for a,b,c,d,e in zip(a,b,c,d,e):
     mm.append([a*(b+e) - c*d]/[e*(c+a)])
for a in mm:
    m.append(abs(a))
```

But I'm getting the error :

> 'Typeerror: unsupported operand type(s) for ?: 'list' and 'list'.

I understand you can't really do arithmetic with lists, but I thought list comprehension would fix this?

How can I fix this?  Is it because the lists are complex?

Comment: What are the values of your lists?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are not using `numpy` (which would be both faster and easier for this sort of problem)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use round brackets for *math expressions*: `()`, not the square: `[]`.

`[]` stands for a list in Python.

Modify the 4th line to

```
mm.append((a*(b+e) - c*d)/(e*(c+a)))
```